# Redirect Loop after adding a code to .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I tried to put a redirect in a my website for CEO  (Search Engine Friendly ) 
i put a code in .htaccess , then i checked here http://www.webconfs.com/redirect-check.php , so it said : (Found redirect to http://www.abosurfmorocco.com/. The Redirect is Search Engine Friendly.), but when i went to the website i got a Redirect Loop error in the browser, i deleted this code in .htaccess, i cleaned browser cookies , but i still can get to the website.
is there is way to resolve this problem , please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is still a 301 Redirect. Check again if there isn't any .htaccess file.
Moved Permanently: http://www.abosurfmorocco.com/ --> http://www.abosurfmorocco.com

Comment: i resolved the problem with the web host but still have problem with  GT mterix , it said 
Analysis Error
Redirect loop detected!

Visiting the page has resulted in an endless chain of redirects. This is usually caused by a problem in your application